# XAML: текст со скроллингом

Tags: wpf, xaml

добрый день.

не могу сообразить, как сделать такую разметку:

должна быть таблица 2x2, в верхней строке в каждой ячейке по кнопке, в нижней в каждой ячейке текст. до сих пор всё понятно.

размеры столбцов должны быть по 50%, это соотношение сохраняется при любом изменении размера окна.

текст может быть длинным и в окно не влезать, поэтому он должен скроллиться. пробовал TextBlock, как там сделать скроллинг, не понял.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему, вам нужно такое:

```
<Grid ShowGridLines="True">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100">
        привет
    </Button>
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100">
        пока
    </Button>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="5"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <TextBlock Text="абра-швабра-кадабра!"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="5"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <TextBlock Text="երեք ույու չորս"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Получается вот что:

[image: пример]

---

Если у вас вертикальное скроллирование, нужно задать высоту клеток (иначе непонятно, с какого момента скроллироваться). И разрешить текстблоку разбиваться на строки:

```
<Grid ShowGridLines="True">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100">
        Чебурашка
    </Button>

    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100">
        Шапокляк
    </Button>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Padding="5"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
        <TextBlock Text="Бамбара, чуфара, скорики, морики, турабо, фурабо, лорики, ёрики"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Padding="5"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
        <TextBlock Text="այբ բեն գիմ"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Получается такое:

[image: ещё пример]

Comment: нужен вертикальный скролл.  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"?

Comment: @user211576: Обновил ответ.

Comment: нет, не совсем получается. можно задать высоту в процентах? повторюсь, текст длинный (гораздо длиннее, чем здесь), фиксированное значение может быть, ну скажем, 120. Но фиксированное значение это плохо, т.к. окно может как угодно переразмериваться.

Comment: @user211576: А если так: `<RowDefinition Height="3*"/><RowDefinition Height="*"/>`?